# $e, \varphi$ and $\pi$ in a right angle

Tags: pi, golden-ratio

\begin{align}
e &= 2.7182\ldots \\    
\varphi &= 1.618 \ldots \\
\pi &= 3.1415\ldots \\
\end{align}

[image: right angle]
\begin{align}
e^2 &= 7.38905\dots \\
\varphi^2 &= 2.61803\ldots \\
\implies e^2 + \varphi^2 &= 10.00708 \ldots \\
&> \pi^2 \\
&= 9.8696 \ldots
\end{align}

$10.00708 - 9.8696 = 0.137485 \Rightarrow 0.1375 \Rightarrow 137.5$deg is the Golden Angle

How come $\pi$ is short by the value of the Golden Angle?

Comment: Not sure what is your question, but the angle on your figure is not a right angle.

Comment: What you seem to be saying is that $e^2+\varphi^2-\pi^2 \approx \dfrac{0.36}{\varphi^2}$.  Since there is not equality, this does not look that special to me

Comment: *10.00708 - 9.8696 = 0.137485>>>> 0.1375 >>>> 137.5deg* : This comparison doesn't make sense since the left hand's unit is the square of your length unit (say, $m^2$) and the right hand's unit is in degrees (or thousands of degrees if I read you well).

Comment: Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question nicely

Comment: I figured it was coincidence more than meaning. Just found it to be a strange coincidence and wondered if there is more to it!

Answer (score 1):

Hunt for near misses for long enough and you will find them.  In this case, the sum is out by more than 1% which seems too much to be interesting.  The coincidental similarity to an angle in degrees is also uninteresting since it depends on the arbitrary choice of 360 degrees in a circle.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a right triangle in your diagram above *precisely* because $\pi^2 \neq \varphi^2 + e^2$.

There is the Kepler triangle, which has sides $(1, \varphi, \sqrt{\varphi})$ for which $$1+\varphi = \varphi^2$$